# how to concatenate data.frame into a single column?

Tags: r

I have created a mock up data like,

```
d1<-structure(list(`1` = c(10L, 15L, 20L), `2` = c(20L, NA, 15L), 
`3` = c(30L, 25L, NA)), .Names = c("1", "2", "3"),
  class = "data.frame",     row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Now I want to convert like,

```
d2<-structure(list(Name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1,10|2,20|3,30",
 "1,15|2,0|3,25", "1,20|2,15|3,0"), class = "factor")),
.Names = "Name",  class     = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The title is very broad, maybe it should be improved so something closer to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've edited the title a bit. Please revise it and see if it still capture crux of the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
d1N <- d1
d1N[is.na(d1N)] <- 0
d1N[] <- paste(col(d1N), as.matrix(d1N), sep=',')

data.frame(Name=do.call(paste, c(d1N, sep='|')))
#           Name
#1 1,10|2,20|3,30
#2  1,15|2,0|3,25
#3  1,20|2,15|3,0
```